# NodeJs error of 'The ESM module loader is experimental' after using --experimental-modules

Tags: node.js, express, babeljs, ionic-native, es6-modules

I wrote this on package.json

```
"start:server": "nodemon --experimental-modules --es-module-specifier-resolution=node src/index server.js"
```

OR

```
 "start:server": "nodemon --experimental-modules server.js"
```

server.js

```
import { LoginPageModule } from './src/app/login/login.module';
```

Error :

```
(node:16628) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
internal/modules/run_main.js:54
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the `.js` to the import, unless you also add `--experimental-specifier-resolution=node`.

This changes node's default `explicit` setting which requires file extensions to be set, which then allows files without an extension to be seen as `.js` files.